# How to get past 24 hours data using SQL in VBScript?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I am using VBScript. I'm connected to an SQL database using an ADODB connection. I wrote an inline SQL query in VBScript.

Requirement is: to fetch all the records from last 24 hours (systemtimestamp - 24 hours). The query is running as expected and fetching data in SQL Server. But if I use the same query in the VBScript file I am not getting the records, it is returning null.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM customer 
WHERE CAST(InsertDate AS DATETIME) > = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME)
```

VBScript code:

```vb
Dim Connection
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL
Dim Server
Dim field
Dim Header
dt= Date
dt = Replace(dt,"/","-")
dt1= DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
dt1 = Replace(dt1,"/","-")
t=FormatDateTime(now, 4)
t1=FormatDateTime(now-24, 4)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

outFile="D:\"

if not objFSO.FileExists(outfile) then
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
else
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(outFile,8,True)
End if

objFile.Write " "& vbCrLf & vbCrLf &"LOG Details on  "

objFile.Write(NOW) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

SQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE CAST(InsertDate AS DATETIME) > = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME)"
'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects
Connection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=DS;UID=id;PWD=pwd;Database=db"
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objFile.Write "1. Connected to the Database" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records
Recordset.Open SQL, Connection
'first of all determine whether there are any records
    If Recordset.EOF Then
    objFile.Write "2. No Records Retrieved From the Database" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    mail()

'if there are records then loop through the fields
    Else
    objFile.Write "2. Records Retrieved From the Database" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    'Send the Email with data
    sendMail()
    End If
'close the connection and recordset objects to free up resources

Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing
```

Comment: If the query works, but not in VBScript, I think you should psot the VBScript code snippet.

Comment: @DanGuzman Good eye, I missed "as expected"

Comment: That code is incomplete. The `If` is missing an `End If`, `objFile` is never intitialized, and both `mail()` and `mail1()` are undefined. How/where do you even check that you're getting a Null response? Please make sure you post a [mcve], otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I only gave the function of code as it is confidential. But as my problem is the script is giving wrong output  while running the sql.

Comment: Hi Ansgar,
As requested I gave the code(not the mail function). Here I am using logfile, if records are retrieved then in log it is recorded that received data from database, otherwise in log it is recorded as no records from db.

Comment: Can anyone help me